Проблема при работе с виртуальным окружением в Pycharm
Проблема в следующем:
Я создаю виртуальное окружение в только что склонированном проекте с помощбю команды
python -m venv venv

И у меня не получается выбрать его в Pycharm - please specify a different sdk name, хотя у я удалил все окружения


Добрый день! Открыта вкладка Python Intepreters, которая пустая. Видимо Pycharm здесь ожидает какую-то версию питона. Я не так давно снес Pycharm, поэтому воспроизвести ситуацию не могу. Попробуйте добавить через значок + интерпретатор. В папке venv/bin есть символьные ссылки на питон, установленный в системе. Можно через них попробовать.
